# Why life expectancy calculate as 1/μ in SIR model?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology, epidemiology

In the SIR model, when the death rate is μ, life expectancy is calculated as 1/μ. Can anyone explain it intuitively?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math SE. Which SIR variant do you have in mind? [Some but not all of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology) have a $\mu$ parameter. It would help if you link to your model therein if it has a dedicated section, or use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to edit the model's equations into your question. Until then, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Mean_lifetime) is the best intuition I can offer you.

Comment: SIR with Demography

Comment: I don't see a variant described that way in the article. You'll have to edit in the equations, or at least link to where you saw that model.

Comment: See below answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive explanation:

Let $L$ be life expectancy (in time units used in the model). Consider a population of size $N$ with ages uniformly distributed from $0$ to $L$. Then, as one unit of time passes, the fraction of individuals of age $>L$ will be exactly $\frac{1}{L}N$.

Comment: This helps a lot

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a death term that looks like: $S' = -\mu S$, you can solve for $S(t) $ explicitly. This gives:
$$S(t) = S_0e^{-\mu t}.$$
The underlying assumption is that the death process is exponentially distributed. For the moment, let $S_0 = 1$. Then integrate $S(t)$ from $t=0$ to $\infty$, you get:
$$\int_0^\infty S(s)ds = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu s}ds = \frac{1}{\mu},$$
which gives you the expected duration in the $S$ compartment assuming an exponential removal rate of $\mu$.